# What is the unit of "output cell size" in IDW in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, interpolation, utm, inverse-distance-weighted

I have a wind speed point data which I interpolated using IDW. While interpolating, it asks for output cell size. I am confused as in it is in which unit?

My data is in UTM projection and WGS 84 datum. Map units and display units are in meters.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2.

Reason that I am confused because if I want 5 Kilometer cell size and I give 5000 value to "output cell size", then it is not taking the value and error is coming.

Comment: Your logic seems correct. Can you edit your question by specfying  what error you receive?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the environment is set to the same coordinate system as the input data (not the map), but maybe this is overwritten in your case (main menu > geoprocessing > environment). From the IDW tool, press the "environment" button, go to "Output coordinates" and manually select you UTM projection. The unit should then be in meters.

As a remark, you can check from the properties of your dataset what is the coordinate system of your data (right click > properties > sources).